# Complex Analysis Proof For Holomorphic Functions in a Disk

Tags: complex-analysis

I am confused about how to prove the following result:

Let $D\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be a disk. How can I show that if $0\in D$ there is no holomorphic function $f:D\to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)^2 = z$ for any $z\in D$?

I don't need a complete solution. I would appreciate any hint!

Comment: $f(z)=\sqrt2 $  and $f(z)=-\sqrt2 $ are  analytic and $f(z)^{2}=2$! There is  no other $f$: $f(z)=\pm \sqrt 2$ for all $z$. What can you say about a real valued analytic function.

Comment: sorry I incorrectly wrote 2 instead of $z$ in the question prompt.

Comment: take logarithmic derivatives so $2f'/f=1/z$ and integrate those on a circle around the origin getting even=odd

Answer (score 0):

As $0\in D$, we get $f(0)=0.$ Therefore the function $g(z)=f(z)/z$ is holomorphic. But $g(z)^2={1/z},$ which gives a contradiction.

**Remark** Similar proof can be made for the equation
$$ f(z)^2=z^{2n+1}+\sum_{k=2n+2}^{\infty}b_kz^k$$ Then $$f(z)=\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}a_kz^k$$ Therefore $f(z)^2=o(z^{2n+1}) $ for $z\to 0,$ which leads to a contradiction.